# Apple Mail always "Expand All Conversations"

Tags: mail.app

In Apple Mail I can set `View -> "Expand All Conversations"` but if I quit Apple Mail and open it again the setting is lost and I have to set it again. Is there any way to keep the setting "Expand All Conversations" always active?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the intention of that menu option is that it's a *command*, not a setting— hence why there's also a "collapse" option.

Clicking "expand all conversations" is the equivalent of clicking the ⧁ on all messages in the current mailbox. Which conversations are expanded seems to only persist for as long as that mailbox is open— switch to a different mailbox and they're all collapsed again.

(At least in Monterey)